# proceed checkout btn redirect to onepage checkout instead of custom checkout extension

Tags: magento-1.9

I installed firecheckout, but when i click proceed checkout in shopping card page it redirect me to onepage checkout instead of firecheckout

Answer (score 0):

Copy below file in your theme and change the redirect link as per your requirement:
file path:

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Checkout/templates/onepage/link.phtml
```